# Python: Deleting from a dict in-place

Tags: python

I have a Python application that performs correlation an large files. It stores those in a dict. Depending on the input files, this dict can become really large, to the point where it does not fit into memory anymore. This causes the system to hang, so I want to prevent this.

My idea is that there are always correlations which are not so relevant for the later processing. These could be deleted without changing the overall result too much. I want to do this when I have not much memory left.

Hence, I check for available memory periodically. If it becomes too few (say, less than 300MB), if delete the irrelevant correlations to gain more space. That's the theory.

Now for my problem: In Python, you cannot delete from a dict while iterating over it. But this is exactly what I need to do, since I have to check each dict entry for relevancy before deleting.

The usual solution would be to create a copy of the dict for iteration, or to create a new dict containing only the elements that I want to preserve. However, the dict might be several GBs big and there are only a few hundred MB of free memory left. So I cannot do much copying since that may again cause the system to hang.

Here I am stuck. Can anyone think of a better method to achieve what I need? If in-place deletion of dict entries is absolutely not possible while iterating, maybe there is some workaround that could save me?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** -- some more information about the dict:

The keys are tuples specifying the values by which the data is correlated.

The values are dicts containing the correlated date. The keys of these dicts are always strings, the values are numbers (int or float).

I am checking for relevancy by comparing the number values in the value-dicts with certain thresholds. If the values are below the thresholds, the particular correlation can be dropped.

Comment: What is the dict value type and how do you check for relevance?

Comment: I have added this information to the original post.

Comment: Are the keys in those value dicts fixed? If so, did you consider an in-memory db instead of a dict, like sqlite?

Comment: Well, there are several modules (kind of like plug-ins) that perform different correlations. For each of these modules, the keys of the value dicts are fixed. At least until you change the correlation algorithm, which happens quite often during testing. So, using a database would mean a great loss of flexibility which is why I would like to find another solution.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that your solution to the problem is prudent.

If you have that much data I recommend you find some bigger tools in your toolbox, a suggestion would be to let a local Redis server help you out.

Take a look at [redis-collections](https://redis-collections.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), that will provide you with a dictionary like object with a redis backend, giving you a sustainable solution.

```
>>> from redis_collections import Dict
>>> d = Dict()
>>> d['answer'] = 42
>>> d
<redis_collections.Dict at fe267c1dde5d4f648e7bac836a0168fe {'answer': 42}>
>>> d.items()
[('answer', 42)]
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks, that would be a solution. Can you make any prediction on how bad that would be for the correlation performance, since I would have to access the harddrive too?

Comment: Of cause performence will decrease a bit, but as Redis is very efficient and uses memcaching I do not think that it will be a problem at all.

Comment: @j0ker, if you try the Redis solution, would you please share your findings?

Comment: I tried it and it seems not be acceptable due to it's write performance. While it does the job of getting much more date into memory than using Pyton-only datatypes, it fails when I'm constantly updating my dict. I tested a small sample which takes 15 seconds without Redis. With Redis I had to abort after 15 minutes.

Comment: Hmm, it does not seem right, can you share the codebase on github, supply testdata, and write a short task description, then I will take a look at a solution in next weekend, thats the best a can do i think..

Answer (score 0):

Are the keys large? If not, you can loop over the dict to determine which entries should be deleted; store the key for each such entry in a list. Then loop over those keys and delete them from the dict.